# Auto Seeding SQL Server AG Combined with Backup/Restore

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2017

Are there special conditions under which the below paragraph from MS Docs is true?  I tested this process on SQL Server 2017 Enterprise Edition and ended up with databases saying not synchronized/recovery pending and could not get them out of this state.

[Combine Backup Restore with Auto Seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/automatic-seeding-secondary-replicas?view=sql-server-ver15#change-the-seeding-mode-of-a-replica)

> It is possible to combine the traditional backup, copy, and restore with automatic seeding. In this case, first restore the database on a secondary replica including all available transaction logs. Next, enable automatic seeding when creating the availability group to "catch up" the secondary replica's database, as if a tail-log backup were restored (see Tail-Log Backups (SQL Server)).

Comment: OOH MAN! I just finished up a huge AG project, and wrote some nifty custom code to handle automatically adding databases to an AG, and then auto seeding them to the secondaries. To get them out of that state run this command --> USE MASTER; ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP ['AGNAME'] MODIFY REPLICA ON 'Replica Name' WITH (SEEDING_MODE = AUTOMATIC)

Comment: @ Lee M - I don't like the backup / restore method for seeding. Automatic seeding works fine.

Comment: For me, the purpose of trying to combine backup/restore and auto seeding is to shorten the time before synchronization occurs.  We have a couple of 100+ GB databases and the auto seeding takes 45 to 50 minutes.  If I can combine them, then it would take 5-10 minutes.

Comment: Lee - Understood, and I get why you are doing it the way you are. If you run the script above it will bring those databases out of the not syncing status.  :)